# Length of NULL cannot be changed error when creating a regression table using stargazer

Tags: r-markdown, linear-regression, stargazer

I have been trying to create a regression table using the Stargazer package in R Markdown But I keep getting the error : length of NULL cannot be changed.

**Here is my code for the regression table:**

```
Model_4 <- lm(formula = demsat ~ education + province + age + sex_r + ethnic + emp_status + sat_govt + ptfeel_cons, data = CES2015 )

probit.model <- glm(demsat ~ education + province + age + sex_r + ethnic + emp_status + sat_govt + ptfeel_cons, data = CES2015)

stargazer(Model_1, probit.model, title = "Table of Regression Model 1 to 4", style = "default", type = "latex")
```

**And here is the output that it gives me, followed with the error message:**

```
length of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changed
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Sun, Apr 12, 2020 - 15:54:24
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Table of Regression Model 1 to 4} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{demsat} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \textit{OLS} & \textit{normal} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 education & $-$0.014$^{***}$ & $-$0.014$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.003) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 province & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 \\ 
  & (0.002) & (0.002) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 age & 0.00002 & 0.00002 \\ 
  & (0.00002) & (0.00002) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 sex\_r & 0.003 & 0.003 \\ 
  & (0.013) & (0.013) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 ethnic & 0.004$^{***}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 emp\_status & 0.006$^{**}$ & 0.006$^{**}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.003) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 sat\_govt & 0.250$^{***}$ & 0.250$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.020) & (0.020) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 ptfeel\_cons & $-$0.012$^{***}$ & $-$0.012$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 Constant & 2.945$^{***}$ & 2.945$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.167) & (0.167) \\ 
  & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 3,911 & 3,911 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.200 &  \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.199 &  \\ 
Log Likelihood &  & $-$7,464.311 \\ 
Akaike Inf. Crit. &  & 14,946.620 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 1.633 (df = 3902) &  \\ 
F Statistic & 122.238$^{***}$ (df = 8; 3902) &  \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

What does this error mean? And how can I get my regression table to show up?

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated it to the actual code

Comment: You have shown us the code that creates `Model_4`, but you are passing `Model_1` to `stargazer()`.

Answer (score 1):

Stargazer can generate tables in three format types: text, html and latex. The default is latex and that's the format of the output you've generated.

Latex is used widely in scientific publishing and good for generating tables in PDFs. In R Markdown, you need to begin the code chunk with the knitr chunk option results = 'asis' in the code chunk header. This tells R Markdown not to try and reformat the output at all so that the latex table code can be interpreted 'asis'. In short, your chunk header should include this:

```
{r results = 'asis'}
```